# Failed to create D3D9 Device!

Tags: directx-9, a-hat-in-time

I was playing A Hat in Time, and suddenly the game crashed. When trying to load the game up again I get the following message:

> Failed to create the D3D9 Device! This can happen if the desktop is locked. Exiting...

I have ran `dxdiag` which says everything is hunky-dory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the standard fixes:

- Reboot your computer.
- [Verify Integrity of Game Files](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335).
- Update your drivers.

People have reported the following fix the issues.

- [Setting Game Launch Options](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947) to `-dx9`.
- Browse Local Files.
  Right click *A Hat in Time*; press *Properties...*; select *Local Files* tab; select *Browse Local Files...*
  This will open an explorer window to `steamapps\common\HatinTime`.
  From here navigate to `HatinTimeGame\Config` and open `HatinTimeSystemSettings.ini`

  Edit game config.
  `steamapps\common\HatinTime\HatinTimeGame\Config\HatinTimeSystemSettings.ini`

  From here there are two reported fixes:

  - Edit `ResX` and `ResY` to smaller values.

    ```
    ResX=1600
    ResY=900
    ```
  - Set `Fullscreen` to false.

    ```
    Fullscreen=False
    ```

For me setting fullscreen to false worked.
The game set my vertical monitor as the default, and then positioned the game on a different monitor.